# How can I transfer the Product backlogs, EPICs, features etc.. from one organisation to another in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure

I have one Org structure created in my Azure DevOps for Eg: Org ABC, under that I have lots of backlog items (epics, features, PB's etc..)
Now I have created a new Org Structure for which I am the owner for Eg: ORG XYZ.
I want to move some of the pending backlog items from previous Org ABC into my new Org XYZ. Can I do that or I need to create those backlog items from scratch in my new Org ? Please help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a push-button solution to this, although it has been a [long-standing customer request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1/365365).

For the work items, you can use the export / import feature.

- [Export to CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#export-list-as-a-csv-file.)
- [Import work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-new-work-items)

You may need to do the same with your cusom process if you didn't use one of the out-of-the box process templates in Azure DevOps. You can use the [process migrator tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator) or the REST API to do this, so it's more involved than the work items.